# Use of Unresolved Identifier with Segmented Control

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a scene in my app that I want to do basic math between two slider bars and a segmented control that the user picks. I am trying to do the math between variables under the segmented controls, but Xcode is giving me a (!) stating

> Use of unresolved identifier "xxxx"

with whatever variable I'm trying to add.
My code is:

```
import UIKit

class DopamineCalculator: UIViewController {

//slider outlets
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderone: UISlider!
//segmentoutlet
@IBOutlet weak var segmentoutlet: UISegmentedControl!


//LABELS
//weight label
@IBOutlet weak var weightlabel: UILabel!
//dosage label
@IBOutlet weak var dosagemg: UILabel!
 //Drip Rate Answer Label
@IBOutlet weak var dripanswer: UILabel!




//ACTIONS!!
//weight slider action
@IBAction func weightslider(sender: UISlider) {

    let weight = Int(sender.value)
    //converts to kgs
    let kgs = Int(sender.value) / Int(2.2)

    weightlabel.text = "\(weight) lbs"
}


//Dosage Desired dosage slider

@IBAction func dosagedesired(sender: UISlider) {

    let dosage = Int(sender.value)



    dosagemg.text = "\(dosage) mg"
}


//CONCENTRATION OPTIONS
@IBAction func concentrationoption(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch segmentoutlet.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:


            dripanswer.text = (kgs) * (dosage) / 800


        case 1:


            dripanswer.text = "1600";



        case 2:


            dripanswer.text = "3200";

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is kgs x dosage / 800 respectively for each case. I can not find an adequate solution online to the unresolved identifier issue.

Comment: `dosage` is  a local variable, only visible in the scope (within the pair of braces) of the `dosagedesired` action. To make is visible in the class you need an instance variable

Comment: are you able to use `dosage` without warning or error?

Comment: How do I create an instance variable?
And yes I am Mr.UB, just not under the segmented control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet ...

// Add variables to be reachable for all methods    
var dosage : Int = 0
var kgs : Double = 0.0
var divisor : Double = 800.0 

@IBAction func dosagedesired(sender: UISlider) {

    // prepend self to variable as it is used
    self.dosage = Int(sender.value)
    dosagemg.text = "\(self.dosage) mg"
    // adding the calculation here
    let result = self.kgs * Double(self.dosage) / self.divisor
    dripanswer.text = "\(result)"
}

@IBAction func weightslider(sender: UISlider) {
    let weight = Int(sender.value)    
    // converts to kgs
    // the same here
    self.kgs = Int(sender.value) / Int(2.2)
    // adding the calculation here
    let result = self.kgs * Double(self.dosage) / self.divisor
    dripanswer.text = "\(result)"
}

@IBAction func concentrationoption(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch segmentoutlet.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
        case 0:                
            self.divisor = 800.0            
        case 1:
            self.divisor = 1600.0
        case 2:
            self.divisor = 3200.0
        default: 
            self.divisor = 800.0
    }
    // finally the calculation 
    let result = self.kgs * Double(self.dosage) / self.divisor
    dripanswer.text = "\(result)"            
}
```

Comment: works perfectly thank you. is there a certain code I should enter in here to allow the "Answer Label" to update as the user change the sliderbar?

Comment: @beans217 How is your slider currently working? Is it not updating the value of UILabel, or what do you actually need? Maybe you could post another question, if it is completely new issue.

Comment: Each slider updates it's own label. But I have two sliders and a segmented control that do math to produce their own Label at the bottom as "Answer". This Label does not update as the user slides the slider but only after a segmented control button is pressed.

Comment: So it updates the label, but not with the correct math for the segment selected. May I ask for your help one more time please? Is there anyway I can message you with the new full code?
 Basically the segmented control is three options to divide by. (800, 1600, and 3200). It does the math for only 800 (i see that we stated to divide by 800 in the code) when you move the sliders, but not for whichever segment has been pressed, and then the slider moved.

Comment: Thank you very much! I greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the variables `kgs` and `dosage` outside of any method i.e. at the class level, along with your outlets

```
//slider outlets
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderone: UISlider!
//segmentoutlet
@IBOutlet weak var segmentoutlet: UISegmentedControl!

//LABELS
//weight label
@IBOutlet weak var weightlabel: UILabel!
//dosage label
@IBOutlet weak var dosagemg: UILabel!
 //Drip Rate Answer Label
@IBOutlet weak var dripanswer: UILabel!

// You should declare the variables here:
var kgs = 0
var dosage = 0
```

And when you use `kgs` and `dosage` inside your methods, remove the word `let` because you're not declaring a variable.

The reason you do this is that you can't access variables declared in a method in another method. In the `concentrationoption` method, you can't access `dosage`, which is defined in `dosagedesired` method.

Comment: @beans217 if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking that check mark

Comment: It did, however, the second answer helped me out more precisely with what I was trying to achieve. Thank you for your input though.